# Snowflake external stage - getting error access denied

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created an external stage for my S3 bucket in snowflake. When I try to access the stage using
List @database.schema.stagename
am getting access denied error. We have checked the S3 bucket policy and fixed the issue.
But
I want to check log in snowflake. is it possible any of the snowflake log will give details about this issue. ? if any where I have to check ?

Answer (score -1):

Open a support ticket(support@snowflake.com) to get details about a specific incident or error.